# Value of array with two dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Can you please help me understand what the following code means and what the value of `number[2][2]` is?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] numbers = new int [3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
            numbers[i][j] = i*j;
        }
```

Comment: It's an array, not an arraylist.

Comment: You know how to deal with an Array. Just think of a two dimensional array as `a single dimensional array of single dimensional arrays`. In Java, that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a multiple dimension array is constructed with multiple one dimensional arrays. In your example `numbers[3][3]` will look like the below array:

```
numbers = [
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 2],
     [0, 2, 4]
]
```

Now when you ask what will be the length of `numbers[0]`? Then it is easy to say 3. `numbers[0]` holds `[0, 0, 0]`. And if you ask what is the value of `numbers[2][2]` then it is 4 ( since array index starts with 0 ).

Now here I put another example.

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
        numbers[0] = new int[2];
        numbers[1] = new int[3];
        numbers[2] = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                numbers[i][j] = j;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I take an array and make the internal array size differently. This array will look like this:

```
numbers = [
     [0, 1],
     [0, 1, 2],
     [0, 1, 2, 3]
]
```

Here I create the first array with size 2, second array with size 3 and third array with size 4, put some data into it and simply print it.

I think you may now visualize what `numbers[0].length` actually means.